# Ajax broken by Wordpress warnings: solve trough ob_start()?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, buffer, ob-start

I am writing a plugin for `WordPress`. My goal is make it work for everyone. Some pages use `ajax` responses. Some users have activated the WP_DEBUG constant that shows errors and warnings from themes and other plugins.

This breaks my Ajax PHPs because I include the `Wordpress` Core, and then WP can show warnings in some blogs!

The old way I solved this, is:

```
<?php
ob_start();
//The wordpress core require
ob_end_clean();

//Now the ajax response:
echo '0';
?>
```

However, one user reported a very strange bug: the `ajax` page never response, only works in Opera, and Google Chrome says: Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED):

Digging in the user web-server, I found that WP configuration, or a plugin or elsewere uses the ob_start("ob gzhandler").

The ob_get_status(true) shows in my working webserver:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [chunk_size] => 4096
            [type] => 1
            [status] => 0
            [name] => default output handler
            [del] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [chunk_size] => 0
            [size] => 40960
            [block_size] => 10240
            [type] => 1
            [status] => 0
            [name] => default output handler
            [del] => 1
        )

)
```

And in the buggy web-server:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [chunk_size] => 4096
            [type] => 1
            [status] => 0
            [name] => default output handler
            [del] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [chunk_size] => 0
            [size] => 40960
            [block_size] => 10240
            [type] => 1
            [status] => 0
            [name] => default output handler
            [del] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [chunk_size] => 0
            [size] => 40960
            [block_size] => 10240
            [type] => 1
            [status] => 0
            [name] => ob_gzhandler
            [del] => 1
        )

)
```

The sequence in my user web-server is:

- My code calls ob_start()
- Include WP core, WP initializes all and call ob_start("ob gzhandler")
- When my code call ob_end_clean() it fails.

I need a safe way to hide the WP warnings, but I can't break GZIP enabled configurations ( some plugin I suspect). If is not possible I prefer leave breaking ajax in warning systems and forget the buffer method.

I think a clean way may be:

```
$buffers = count(ob_get_status(true));
ob_start();
//The wordpress core require
if (count(ob_get_status(true)) == $buffers + 1) {
ob_end_clean();
} else {
ob_flush();
}
//Now the ajax response:
echo '0';
```

But I'm afraid some of the infinite combinations through PHP versions and configs, WP versions, plugins and configurations breaks somebody. What do you think is a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: If someone enables display_errors on a live site, they probably deserve a non-working site. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave any spaces or lines before the open php tag in any files that are required by your plugin (or functions.php) it will break Wordpress AJAX.

BREAKS AJAX:

```
 <?php
```

DOESN'T BREAK AJAX:

```
<?php
```